# C# OLE DB経由とAccessとでSQLの実行結果が違う

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

お助けください。

例えば、ふりがなが「おか」から始まる人物を検索しようとすると、「おが」から始まる人も
ヒットしてしまいます。
Accessのクエリではこのような問題は起こりません。
なぜこのようなことが起こるのか、分かる方はいますでしょうか。

**環境**
Windows 10 64bit
Access 2013 64bit

**実行部分のコード**

```
var connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source =" + dbfilePath;
DbConnection = new OleDbConnection( connectionStr );
DbConnection.Open();
DbCommand = new OleDbCommand { Connection = DbConnection };

var sql = "SELECT * FROM [名簿] WHERE [ふりがな] Like 'おか%'"
var dataTable = new DataTable();

using ( var sqlCommand = new OleDbCommand( sql, DbConnection ) )
    using ( var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter( sqlCommand ) )
        adapter.Fill( dataTable );
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。本当に助かりました。不具合だったのですね。昨日は1日悩みました。
それにしてもMSはなぜこの古い問題を放置しているのでしょう。
Jet4.0での問題をACEエンジンでも引き継いでいるとは、解せません。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Microsoft Jet 4.0の既知の不具合](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/kb/935525)です。
簡単に言うと、Access以外からクエリを発行した場合に`が`の内部表現が`か゛`のように二文字になるため、ワイルドカードの直前が清音の場合に濁音も該当してしまうという現象になります。

SQLで除外したいのであれば、

```
InStr(1, [ふりがな], 'おが', 1) <> 1
```

のような条件を追加する必要があるかと思います。